# Colour regulated genes in Volcano plot - ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

Hi I'm very new in R and I'm struggling trying to modify an R code that I found on internet when learning how to make a volcano plot.

This code is to make volcano plots using ggplot2 and the problem I have is that I want to colour the up- and down-regulated proteins instead of colouring the proteins above the specified threshold. The code I'm using is the following:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")

gene_list <- read.table("/Users/Javi/Desktop/gene_list.csv", header=T, sep=",")

require(ggplot2)
##Highlight genes that have an absolute fold change > 2 and a p-value < 0.05
gene_list$threshold = as.factor(abs(gene_list$logFC) > 2 & gene_list$P.Value < 0.05)

##Construct the plot object
g = ggplot(data=gene_list, aes(x=logFC, y=-log10(P.Value), colour=my_palette)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.4, size=5) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    xlim(c(-10, 10)) + ylim(c(0, 15)) +
    xlab("log2 fold change") + ylab("-log10 p-value")
g
```

What I would like to do is to colour in red (for example) the logFC values > 1.3 and in blue the logFC values < -1.3

The csv file I'm using is just an example and would be something like this:

```
    logFC   P.Value
a   2       0.04
b   5       0.04
c   8       0.04
d   4       0.000005
e   7       0.01
f   1       0.04
g   -6      0.0001
h   -8      0.04
```

Thanks very much for your help in advance.
Cheers
Javi

Answer (score 1):

Create a new color flag on your dataframe:

```
gene_list$color_flag <- ifelse(gene_list$logFC > 1.3, 1, ifelse(gene_list$logFC < -1.3, -1, 0))
```

Then add `fill = color_flag` to your `aes`.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks very much for your answer. When I do as you said I get the following error:

`> gene_list$color_flag <- ifelse(gene_list$logFC > 1.3, 1, ifelse(gene_list$logFC < -1.3, -1, 0))
> g = ggplot(data=gene_list, aes(x=logFC, y=-log10(P.Value), fil=color_flag, colour=my_palette)) +
+     geom_point(alpha=0.4, size=5) +
+     theme(legend.position = "none") +
+     xlim(c(-10, 10)) + ylim(c(0, 15)) +
+     xlab("log2 fold change") + ylab("-log10 p-value")
> g`

Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:logFC, -log10(P.Value), color_flag